# how to get BrowserManager play nice with SWFObject (Flex 3)

Tags: flex3, embed, swfobject

I need to get the URL of the HTML where the SWF is embedded. I found out that it should be a piece of cake with BrowserManager, but unfortunately I use SWFObject to embed swf in html! and BrowserManager doesn't like that!! 
could someone help me with this?
cheers

Comment: come on! theres gotta be someone out there who knows how to do that!! ???

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by changing the history.js file

comment out these lines:;

```
        /*
    if (players.length == 0 || players[0].object == null) {
        var tmp = document.getElementsByTagName('embed');
        players = tmp;
    }
    */
```

and these:

```
        /*
    if (player == null || player.object == null) {
        player = document.getElementsByTagName('embed')[0];
    }
    */
```

these will make them play nicely together :-)